# Convert Text to Image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text

Is there any way I can convert the input text into an image.  What I am exactly trying to do is type some text into a textbox and display it on div. When I click on a button the text copied to div should be changed to an image. Does anyone know anything about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need some server side actions here.  ImageMagick perhaps...

Comment: You can write your text over the image by positioning the text...

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: @Solutioner That question is about PHP, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can do this using a hidden canvas element and converting that to an image using `toDataURL`. Your code would look something like this:

```js
var tCtx = document.getElementById('textCanvas').getContext('2d'), //Hidden canvas
    imageElem = document.getElementById('image'); //Image element
  
// Text input element
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  tCtx.canvas.width = tCtx.measureText(this.value).width;
  tCtx.fillText(this.value, 0, 10);
  imageElem.src = tCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
  console.log(imageElem.src);
}, false);
```

```css
canvas{
    border: 1px black solid;
}
#textCanvas{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='textCanvas' height=20></canvas>
<img id='image'>
<br>
<textarea id='text'></textarea>
```

​

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amaan/WxmQR/1/)

Comment: Helped.. Thanks. Will figure out the rest thing myself. :)

Answer (score 2):

The canvas approach suggested by Amaan is definitely today's approach to generating images client-side.

In the past, the most common solution was to use a library like [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/). From the [Cufon wiki page on its usage](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/Usage) comes this snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('h1'); // Works without a selector engine
    Cufon.replace('#sub1'); // Requires a selector engine for IE 6-7, see above
</script>
```

Cufon generates the client-side version of the font up-front. This means it just adds static files on your web server, instead of generating the images on the web server (like with ImageMagick).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ImageMagick on your server side. Depending on what kind of framework you use, you may have to write some nice shell scripts.

OR

You can check this out:

http://www.blitline.com/docs/functions