# Can you set the information of a div as a background-image of another div?

Tags: html, css, jquery-plugins, background-image, parallax

For a class project i have an idea to make a forum similar to this but where users get paid for answering. So an idea i came up with is that at the home screen where all the questions are listed, the users entire question could be used as the background image of the div then use parallax scrolling so when u scroll down you see more of the question. Is it even possible to do this??

Comment: Can you explain a little more? 
You want to show a question that is in a div in another one?

Comment: For example, the homepage of this site shows a list of all the questions and when you click on one of those questions, you are taken to a page with that question and the details, such as this page you are on at the moment. My idea was is it possible to show *this page* as the background image of the same question in the home page. for example http://jsfiddle.net/jmann1622/rd451p0e/

Comment: Dynamicly and like this, i don't think so ( at least not easily )

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to use Parallax to show/hide your questions so :

You can convert a text to image with some JavaScript : [Convert Text to Image using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328714/convert-text-to-image-using-javascript)

I think that it's what you're looking for but didn't tested it ^^

Answer (score 0):

parallax css

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: 'segoe ui';
}
.block-parallax {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.block-parallax .parallax-bg {
    background-attachment: fixed;    
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1170px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.block-parallax .md-box {
    padding: 200px 0 200px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.block-parallax .md-box h1 {
    color: #fff;
}
.block-parallax-1 .parallax-bg {
    background-image: url('http://maque.org.ua/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/html5.jpg');
}
.block-parallax-2 .parallax-bg {
    background-image: url('http://myrusakov.ru/images/articles/html5-local-storage.jpg');
}
.block-parallax-3 .parallax-bg {
    background-image: url('http://www.webdesignmagazine.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/html5_structure.png');
}
.block-parallax-4 .parallax-bg {
    background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQog6awkbZ2gnKtf5Z_bvDJInkn2aBOXti_oWB8LvC1uiJS-Rdv');
}
h2 {
    color: #555;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="block-parallax block-parallax-1">
    <div class="parallax-bg"></div>
    <div class="md-box">
         <h1>background 1</h1>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="block-parallax   block-parallax-2">
    <div class="parallax-bg"></div>
    <div class="md-box">
         <h1>background 2</h1>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="block-parallax  block-parallax-3">
    <div class="parallax-bg"></div>
    <div class="md-box">
         <h1>background 3</h1>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="block-parallax  block-parallax-4">
    <div class="parallax-bg"></div>
    <div class="md-box">
         <h1>background 4</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think that he wants to have the background X as background image to have the same animation but not sure