# Javascript - How to convert text into image

Tags: javascript, html

I need to convert the text into the image using the Javascript. I tried 
**[convert-text-to-image-using-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328714/convert-text-to-image-using-javascript)**. 
 But here in my script I have the bold & italics also in text. With that it is not converting the bold directly, it simply shows the normal text.

For Ex: if I give like this "**S**tack**O**ver**F**low" It gives "StackOverFlow" not the bold ones

*Updated*

I am able to enter the Bold, Italic characters in the text filed, but get the value of the text filed in my JS side I am getting the normal text. There also I need to get the formatted text.

Comment: Here S is image or text?

Comment: what is your exact try.. where you can entered the styled font.. in normal HTML textarea?

Comment: Do you have the code for us, so we can review it?

Comment: @MayankVadiya here S is text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html input or textarea cant manage different styles within their value, you can use a wysiwyg like [this](http://wysiwygjs.github.io/) then extract the html and parse it.

based on my example link you can do this:

```
jQuery('.wysiwyg-editor').contents()
```

this will return an array with every html elements, then use what you ve tryed before.

Hope this help

Comment: I think it is fine, but I didn't get how to use that in my html

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the quesiton / answer you already checked

```
var tCtx = document.getElementById('textCanvas').getContext('2d'), 
    width,
    imageElem = document.getElementById('image'); //Image element
tCtx.font="30px Arial Bold"
width = tCtx.measureText("S").width;
tCtx.fillText("S", 0, 10);
tCtx.translate(width, 0);
tCtx.font="30px Arial"
width = tCtx.measureText("tack").width;
tCtx.fillText("tack", 0, 10);
tCtx.translate(width, 0);
tCtx.font="30px Arial Bold"
width = tCtx.measureText("O").width;
tCtx.fillText("O", 0, 10);
tCtx.translate(width, 0);
```

and so on...

```
imageElem.src = tCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
```

Basically you have to change font style and write the text piece by piece.
​

Comment: we can't change piece by piece, because this is the dynamic text entered by User. We didn't when he will use the bold and where he will use the Italic

Comment: another solution is to use fabricJS iText capability to render text with style. What you need is a parser of rich text to fabricjs style for text. Check fabricjs.com to see if it is something you want to handle.
This will allow you to handle colors, underlines, strike trought, different fonts and background color, out of the box.

Comment: don't mind, I updated the question. Can you check it once

Comment: Yes mind it. To write images in js you have to use canvas. Canvas is used as i showed you. You can write a software that parse the formatted text and use canvas piece by piece OR use a library that does it for you. There is no quick hack script that will solve your problem. You have to edit your question and add what editor are you using to have a change to be helped

Comment: I am using http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php to my div & able to enter the text in different styles and I am trying to get the value by using $('#input').text(); but getting the normal text only