# How to show normal alphabets as icons in React JS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, font-awesome

Is there any way to show normal alphabets( like A, B X, Y, etc) as icons in React?

I am experimenting with Fontawesome https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fontawesome but unable to find any way to show alphabets as icons.

E.g. [image]  [image]

Comment: Hi @artgb, have uploaded couple of examples.

Comment: I found the similar solution here in closed topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328714/convert-text-to-image-using-javascript

Comment: You should try converting to svgs