# Javascript Signature Package that can handle both Text-to-Signature and Signature Pad

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project that is in need of a signature pad. I know there are Signature Packages that'll handle user input and save the image OR let the user type in their name and that'll be converted into a particular font and saved as an image.

Is there a package that can handle both?

I am looking for a JavaScript package. Or any package that supports .NET 4.8 and 6.0.

I have tested Signature Pad by Xamarin and jSignature JS Package and some other packages for text to signature. But none of them support both. So its either this is that.

It'll be helpful to find a package that'll handle both since this will be used in other projects in future as well.

Comment: TBH I don't think your going to get your wish text to image (signature) could be possible. 
using something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070365/how-to-generate-an-image-from-text-on-fly-at-runtime

Javascript Image - https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad

Comment: Also using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865958/how-to-convert-text-to-image-with-font-style-using-javascript is a good post - using that alongside a 'signature font' would also help.