# canvas: modify resolution

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have made a function that can convert text to image according to this link:

[Convert Text to Image using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328714/convert-text-to-image-using-javascript/12328759)

```
<canvas id='textCanvas' height=20></canvas>
<img id='image'>
<br>
<textarea id='text'></textarea>
```

js

```
var tCtx = document.getElementById('textCanvas').getContext('2d'),
    imageElem = document.getElementById('image');

document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keyup', function (){
    tCtx.canvas.width = tCtx.measureText(this.value).width;
    tCtx.fillText(this.value, 0, 10);
    imageElem.src = tCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(imageElem.src);
}, false);
```

jsfiddle of the  linked post: http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/WxmQR/1/

But it seems that the resolution is two low to use, how can I modify the resolution in this case?

Comment: May be you just need to enlarge text? You can set font size by using `ctx.font='30px arial';`

Comment: @Darth Thanks for your reply! But the result don't change.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle of the linked post: http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/WxmQR/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `context.font = ...` **before** you use `context.fillText(...)` to change the way text is rendered (as suggested by [Darth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4782423/darth))

[canvas fillText() method](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_filltext.asp)

(I changed your canvas height to 200 to fit the text and changed the position it is drawn to `0, 100`)

```js
var tCtx = document.getElementById('textCanvas').getContext('2d'),
  imageElem = document.getElementById('image');

document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('input', function() {
  tCtx.canvas.width = tCtx.measureText(this.value).width;
  tCtx.font = "60px sans-serif"
  tCtx.fillText(this.value, 0, 100);
  imageElem.src = tCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id='textCanvas' height=200></canvas>
<img id='image'>
<br>
<textarea id='text'></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you! I really put `tCtx.font = "60px sans-serif"` on the wrong line. I also adjusted the height of canvas, however, the text is cut... the upper part of text disappear

(http://jsfiddle.net/sytai/qfgovm6b/1/)

Comment: It's because you write it at position `(0, 10)` which is as far as I understand the bottom left corner of the text. In my example I changed this Y value to 100 to move it down