# Vue using js in script to refer to elements

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom, vuejs2

So I'm following a post in stackoverflow [Convert Text to Image using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328714/convert-text-to-image-using-javascript) but in vue Js. I can't seem to get this working, it's throwing me this error

```
serve.vue?bf12:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')
    at eval (serve.vue?bf12:27:1)
    at Object../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js?!./dev/serve.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (app.js:997:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849:30)
    at fn (app.js:151:20)
    at eval (serve.vue?5c0c:1:1)
    at Module../dev/serve.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (app.js:962:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849:30)
    at fn (app.js:151:20)
    at eval (serve.vue?061e:1:1)
```

Here's my code, it's simple enough

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <canvas id="textCanvas" height="20" />
    <img id="image" />
    <br />
    <textarea id="text" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
var tCtx = document.getElementById("textCanvas").getContext("2d"), //Hidden canvas
  imageElem = document.getElementById("image");

document.getElementById("text").addEventListener(
  "keyup",
  function () {
    tCtx.canvas.width = tCtx.measureText(this.value).width;
    tCtx.fillText(this.value, 0, 10);
    imageElem.src = tCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(imageElem.src);
  },
  false
);
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to go into rewriting this into vue right now. But you should use the framework for things like this, that's what the framework is for. Get a ref to the canvas and operate on it directly. Assign events with vue not stock js _you need or really should use the framework_.

Comment: Vue has is own ways of listening to [events](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#key-modifiers), same goes for [selecting](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) an element. Try using the provided methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rendering engine hasn't rendered the HTML at the point in time when you make the call to `documents.getElementById('textCanvas')`.

In fact, to be honest, your code is hardly Vue at all. Vue has a lifetime hook called `mounted`, which occurs when the rendering engine has finished rendering the component. In order to use this, you'd convert the code above to actual Vue.

Something akin to this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <canvas ref="canvas" height="20" />
    <img id="image" />
    <br />
    <textarea @keyup="handleKeyUp" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    canvas() {
      return this.$refs.canvas;
    }; 
  },
  methods: {
    handleKeyUp() {
       // Do your thing with "this.canvas"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I really suggest you to learn the basic concept and syntax of Vue, before venturing into something like this.